# confusion : law of f(x)

Tags: probability

Let $x$ a random variable and $y=f(x)$.

$x$ has distribution $\phi_X$ and $y$ has distribution $\phi_Y$.

What is the right way of writing the law of $y$? :

(1)

$$P(Y \in A)=\int_{A} \phi_Y(y) dy = \int 1_{\{x\in f^{-1}(A)\}} \phi_Y[f(x)] f'(x) dx$$

or :

(2)

$$P(Y \in A)=P(f(X) \in A)=\int 1_{\{x\in f^{-1}(A)\}}  \phi_X(x) dx$$

I want to be sure that both are correct. if not could you me tell me why?

Comment: The second is correct, (assuming $f$ bijective )the first has a $y$ which isn't supposed to be there, just integrate the density

Comment: @Ant Indeed. is this correct now?

Comment: Not completely, you're missing an absolute value. I added an answer showing why the two integrals are equal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following assumes $f$ monotone (as it must be the case if it's bijective)

You have $$P(Y \in A) = \int_A \phi_Y(y)dy$$ Setting $y = f(x)$ we get $dy = f'(x) dx$, hence

$$P(Y \in A) = \int 1_{\{x \in f^{-1}(A)\}} \phi_Y(f(x)) |f'(x)| dx$$

(Note the absolute value;it is necessary because if $f$ is increasing, then the extreme of integration are in the correct order and $f'(x) > 0$, so we're good. But if it is decreasing, $f'(x) < 0$ but we have to exchange the extreme of integration; a minus pops up making it $|f'(x)|$)

But the two formula must both be right; that is it, for every event $A$, it must hold that

$$\int 1_{\{x \in f^{-1}(A)\}} \phi_Y(f(x)) |f'(x)| dx = \int 1_{\{x\in f^{-1}(A)\}}  \phi_X(x) dx$$

This is enough to imply that the integrands must be equal, that is

$$\phi_Y(f(x)) |f'(x)| = \phi_X(x)$$

Now setting $y = f(x)$ we get

$$\phi_Y(y) |f'(f^{-1}(y))| = \phi_X(f^{-1}(y))$$

Calling for simplicity $h(y) = f^{-1}(y)$, we notice that $\displaystyle |f'(f^{-1}(y))| = \frac 1{|h'(y)|}$ (usual formula for derivative of inverse) so we get

$$\phi_Y(y) = \phi_X(h(y)) \cdot |h'(y)|$$

As it is indeed the case.